# Embedded Resource location within the assembly

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource, .net-assembly

How can we discover the location of an embedded resource within a .Net assembly? By "location", I mean the beginning and ending byte positions in the assembly. Is there any tool or some sample code to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you want to know this?

Comment: You can get the resource by calling `GetManifestResourceStream`. Any reason why you need the position?

Comment: We are working on a solution to protect the embedded resources within an assembly, so we need to be know the architecture of the assembly resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your looking for is a [PE File](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable&ei=gZwoTt6eOcO70AHrrJzPCg&usg=AFQjCNEOHtAIpfFZTb-SI9tntCFO9o9oIQ) reader/parser.  The complete specification is located on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119

**Managed Resources:**

This parser looks pretty close to what you are after:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/asmex.aspx

And there are several other PE file readers, [this one also looks promising](http://perwapi.codeplex.com/) however does not specifically call out managed resources.  You might also look at Kris Stanton's [Exploring pe file headers using managed code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kstanton/archive/2004/03/31/105060.aspx).

**Win32 Resources:**

Win32 resources are much easier.  Many of the same PE readers will offset into the file to locate the resources.  Once there, there is a well defined set of structures that define the layout of the resources.  [MSDN has defined these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [others have written about it](http://www.skynet.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/resfmt.txt).  A few google searches should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do trial and error. Check the byte structure of resource which you know is embedded and try to locate the same using Hex Editor. If you don't have the resource, you may try extracting using Resource Hacker:
http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/